# IBM MobileFirst 7.1 - WL.Server.getActiveUser returning null immediately after being set

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server

Here is the code I am working with

```
function createUser(realm, userid, displayName, sessionToken, devicePrint){
    var userIdentity = {
            'userId' : userid,
            'displayName' : displayName, 
            attributes: {
                'credentials' : sessionToken,
                'authenticatedDate' : new Date(),
                'devicePrint' : devicePrint
            }
    };

    LOG.info("Realm = " + realm + "\n UserIdentity = " + JSON.stringify(userIdentity));

    WL.Server.setActiveUser(realm, null);
    WL.Server.setActiveUser(realm, userIdentity);

    var user = WL.Server.getActiveUser(realm);
    LOG.info("User = " + JSON.stringify(user));
}
```

Everything looks good when I call WL.Server.setActiveUser(realm, userIdentity); (Params are all populated and look correct). Immediately after I call WL.Server.getActiveUser on that same exact realm, it is returning null.

I suspect session independent mode, but I have confirmed it is set to false.

```
mfp.session.independent=false
mfp.attrStore.type=httpsession
```

This is my procedures XML congifuration (the procedure that calls the createUser() function)

```
<procedure name="validateUserId" securityTest="wl_unprotected">
    <displayName>Validate UserID</displayName>
</procedure>
```

What else could it be?

*Edit:* authenticationConfig.xml

```
    <realms>
        <!-- Realm used once authentication completes -->
        <realm loginModule="CustomMFALoginModule" name="CustomMFAAuthenticatorRealm">
            <className>com.worklight.integration.auth.AdapterAuthenticator</className>
            <parameter name="login-function" value="AuthAdapter.onAuthRequired"/>
            <parameter name="logout-function" value="AuthAdapter.logout"/>
        </realm>

        <!-- Realm used on validate user and challenge calls from MFA -->
        <realm loginModule="CustomMFAInitLoginModule" name="CustomMFAAuthenticatorInitRealm">
            <className>com.worklight.integration.auth.AdapterAuthenticator</className>
            <parameter name="login-function" value="AuthAdapter.onAuthRequired"/>
            <parameter name="logout-function" value="AuthAdapter.logout"/>
        </realm>

        <realm loginModule="StrongDummy" name="SampleAppRealm">
            <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.FormBasedAuthenticator</className>
        </realm>

        <realm loginModule="rejectAll" name="SubscribeServlet">
            <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.HeaderAuthenticator</className>          
        </realm>                
    </realms>

    <loginModules>
        <loginModule expirationInSeconds="-1" name="CustomMFALoginModule">
            <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.NonValidatingLoginModule</className>
        </loginModule>

        <loginModule expirationInSeconds="-1" name="CustomMFAInitLoginModule">
            <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.NonValidatingLoginModule</className>
        </loginModule>

        <loginModule expirationInSeconds="-1" name="StrongDummy">
            <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.NonValidatingLoginModule</className>
        </loginModule>

        <loginModule expirationInSeconds="-1" name="requireLogin">
            <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.SingleIdentityLoginModule</className>
        </loginModule>

        <loginModule expirationInSeconds="-1" name="rejectAll">
            <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.RejectingLoginModule</className>
        </loginModule>              
    </loginModules>
```

SecurityTests

```
    <securityTests>
        <customSecurityTest name="MFAAuthenticated-securityTest">
            <test realm="wl_authenticityRealm" step="1"/>
            <test isInternalUserID="true" realm="CustomMFAAuthenticatorRealm" step="1"/>
        </customSecurityTest>

        <customSecurityTest name="SubscribeServlet">
            <test isInternalUserID="true" realm="SubscribeServlet"/>
        </customSecurityTest>
     </securityTests>
```

Comment: Can you please share realm configuration in authenticationConfig.xml?
I tried the same code in my local environment and It's working.

Comment: @yogesh I have added the authenticationConfig.xml, for this particular call the realm being used is "CustomMFAAuthenticatorInitRealm"

Comment: It looks fine from here. Are you getting any error in client or server side logs?

Comment: @yogesh The only error's i'm getting are NPE's when my code gets to the getActiveUser() portion of my code, when trying to retrieve attributes set to the user object. I'm not seeing any Worklight errors or anything, it's very strange. Everything worked fine on 7.0. I'm at a loss for other ideas on what could be causing this.

Comment: Can you try with a new mobilefirst project

Comment: @NazmulHasan Started down this path yesterday, gonna finish it up  today. Hopefully that fixes whatever is wrong. Thanks for the tip

Comment: @NazmulHasan same issues... this mfp server is derailing my entire project. 7.0 worked, but 7.1 is two steps back.

Answer (score 0):

Well , could you try to download MFP  The latest from fix center  http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg2C7000003 .

Hopefully that will be fixes  otherwise  you should be handled as a PMR (support ticket). Once you open the PMR, please mention its number in the question.

**UPDATE**

for session independent mode,

```
mfp.session.independent=false
mfp.attrStore.type=httpsession
```

Browser not work perfectly better use desktop browser to test

The other thing is that, To test, you need to use either simulators/emulators or physical devices.

Comment: Question about the patch, are these fixes included in the Eclipse plugin update? looks like the fix is 1240, and my server is showing version 1240

Comment: Where are you deployed it local or production server, client set emulator, devices or browser .everywhere getting Same issue?

Comment: We have a websphere host as well as local, both are giving me the same results. Also occurs in browser based calls as well as from emulators like Android,  iOS seems to work fine though...

Comment: browser not work perfectly better use desktop browser to test .

Comment: The other thing is that, To test, you need to use either simulators/emulators or physical devices.

Comment: @hitch.united I try to share my knowledge.if you can be solved   particular the  problem share please !

Comment: I am going to continue debugging first thing Monday morning! I appreciate all of your help :D

Comment: I ended up opening a PMR with IBM, coworkers using mac's can hit my local server and it works, also iOS emulators work. Android does not work, and calling the adapter through eclipse still fails. I'm not sure where to turn at this point. So far the only help I got through the PMR is quotes from the documentation that I have read at least 20 times lol.